# Having trouble with curl on wamp server

Tags: php, curl, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have following code to fetch `Instagram` data using curl. The strange thing is that, this same code is working on my Ubuntu os but when I am trying on WAMP server on Windows 10 its not working and not getting any results. I have also check that api is working well and returning data + curl is enable.

Any idea about this issue?

```
$AccessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;
$Url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/canonfanatic/media/recent?access_token=".$AccessToken;
$Ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($Ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$Result = curl_exec($Ch);
curl_close($Ch);
$Result = json_decode($Result);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($Result); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: did you check that curl is enable or browse any javascript error in console ?

Comment: Yes I have checked that and also tried same code in xampp server but no luck :(

Comment: have you try something like uncommenting the extension=php_curl.dll in the xampp\apache\bin\php.ini file then restart the server

Comment: No I have never touched with php.ini file.

Comment: I have checked php.ini file and there is no `;` before `extension=php_curl.dll` line.

Comment: Then go to this path xampp\apache\bin\php.ini and find "php_curl" then make extension=php_curl.dll; to extension=php_curl.dll that means you need to remove semi colon after this. restart xampp hope this will help you

Comment: Add me to skype : samumaretiya

Comment: I have already removed but still not working.

Comment: Can you see if the $Result is true, if its not check the curl errors ?

Comment: @CodeTweetie I am nothing getting in `$Result`.

Comment: Which I think is false which means the curl request hasn't worked. What about the curl error ?

Comment: I am not getting any error on web page when I run above code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a `https` address in your URL parameter you also need to enabled `php_openssl` extension.

Comment: anything else i have to change?